# How to return property of a resource using jena API in Java?

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology

How to return all properties in model involving the specified resource(as subject or object)...?

A method which returns string[] of properties related to that resource.

Comment: I would advise against prematurely mapping from RDF objects to strings, and Java collections are far more useful than arrays. I suggest you think in terms of `Collection<Property>`, rather than `String[]` to hold the predicates you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no equivalent to `listSubjectsWithProperty` to return all the predicates in a model or all the predicates for a given subject. It is pretty easy to implement though:

With a Jena `SimpleSelector` you can traverse the model and constraint the traversal to certain conditions. In this case I filter only the statements that have as subject `someRelevantSubject`:

```
SimpleSelector selector = new SimpleSelector(null, null, (RDFNode)null) {
    public boolean selects(Statement st)
        { return st.getSubject().equals(someRelevantSubject);}
}
```

Using the selector, iterate the model and add the predicates and add the predicates into a standard Java set:

```
StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements(selector);
while(it.hasNext()) {
   Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
   some_set.add(stmt.getPredicate().toString());
}
```

If you want all the distinct predicates regardless the subject just return `true` in the selector always.